# Electron write json file working in dev but not in dist

Tags: json, node.js, electron, fs, electron-builder

I'm working on an app build with Electron and a config file is saved after login.
When the app is reopened in development, it works, but when it's reopened after being distributed with electron-builder, I have to login again.

**Code**

```
const {writeFile} = require('fs');
const {join} = require('path');

function write(config) {
    writeFile(join(__dirname, './config.json'), JSON.stringify(config, null, 4), (err) => {
        cb(err);
    })
}

write(someJsonObject);
```

**Project:**
Electron 1.7.11
Electron-builder 19.55.2
Node 8.8.1

Answer (score 5):

First check your are not building asar file for your production app since it is read-only and you are trying to write directly to `__dirname`. 
My suggestion is to use writable directory for your configuration file, for example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const _HOME_ = require('os').homedir();
const _SEP_ = require('path').sep;
const _APPHOME_ = `${_HOME_}${_SEP_}.myapp${_SEP_}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(_APPHOME_)) {//Check dir exists or create it
    fs.mkdir(_APPHOME_, '0777', true, function () {
        console.log('Created app home dir :)');
    });
}
fs.writeFile(_APPHOME_ + 'config.json'), JSON.stringify(config, null, 4), (err) => {
            cb(err);
});
```

Of course, you may want to accommodate this solution to your needs. Hope works for you!